# Source code pretty-printer / beautifier / formatter for minified HTML/CSS/JS using only code I can trust?

Tags: formatting

I am reverse engineering foreign web site and have a lot of minified code for CSS/HTML/JS.

What package or tricks allow to beautify code?

I am usually replace `\([{}]\)` to `\1\n` and <kbd>C-x h</kbd> <kbd>C-M-\</kbd> (`indent-region`) but would like something better.

I tried these packages from `package-list-packages`:

- `json-reformat` - doesn't work on JS file
- `web-beautify` depends on `npm -g install js-beautify`

Comment: what's the problem with `web-beautify`?

Comment: I didn't like unsigned installation from Web. `js-beautify` isn't in Debian packages...

Comment: You could pipe HTML through http://www.html-tidy.org/ with `M-|`. Modern web browsers have build-in beautifiers, and there's a small chance source maps were left on production servers, which would make things a lot easier for you.